# Ionic Swiping Between Pages

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I looked through past posts but couldn't find much help to my question. Is there any way to implement a feature in the Ionic Framework to allow swiping between pages of an app? For example, you open up the app to the home page, and sliding finger across the screen from right to left would bring you to a new page.

The image below shows an example of what I want it to be

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Check this Ionic 3 Swipeable example tutorial https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-3-create-swipeable-draggable-tab-pages-application-in-ionic-3/

Answer (score 1):

There is not direct support for having separate pages sliding. However, you can use [Ionic slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/).

With slides, you need to have everything in a single page (i.e. single .TS and .html file), and show different things based on what slide number you are on. This means you virtually show three pages, one per slide, but you code them all on a single Ionic page (single .TS and .html file).

You will need a state variable `curPage` to store the current slide number that changes as the user swipes. Using `*ngIf='curPage=1'`, you show contents of your virtual page 1.

You can use [Ionic tabs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/), which support separate pages, but they are tabs and not swipable.

Comment: Ugh! If only I knew this existed before I created my own thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sideswipe directive I created for this exact purpose.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";
import { SWIPE_DIRECTION } from "../constants/constants";

@Directive({
  selector: '[sideSwipe]'
})
export class SwipeDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Output() swipeLeft: EventEmitter<any>;
  @Output() swipeRight: EventEmitter<any>;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.swipeRight = new EventEmitter<any>();
    this.swipeLeft = new EventEmitter<any>();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'swipeend', (event: any) => {
      if (event.direction === SWIPE_DIRECTION.rightToLeft) {
        this.swipeLeft.emit();
      } else {
        this.swipeRight.emit();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

with SWIPE_DIRECTION being a constant with two props:

```
export const SWIPE_DIRECTION = {
  rightToLeft: 2,
  leftToRight: 1
};
```

Make sure you declare and export your `sideswipe` directive. And then use in your html as follows:

```
<ion-content sideSwipe (swipeLeft)="nextPage()" (swipeRight)="previousPage()">
</ion-content>
```

Of course, one caveat is that you'll need to apply this directive to all pages where you want to use the swipe functionality. Please note that it doesn't offer any animations.

Comment: This will swipe between images, not pages.

Comment: This basically offers the 'swipe event'. So essentially, you could apply this directive to a <ion-content> and handle navigation on left and right swipe events. Of course, you'll have to apply the directive to all pages where you might use this swipe functionality. Disclaimer: This however doesn't offer any animation. **I have edited my answer**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [super-tabs.](https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs) It can be used in addition to Ionic tabs and they are implemented in the same fashion:

```
<super-tabs>
<super-tab [root]="page1" title="First page"></super-tab>
<super-tab [root]="page2" title="Second page"></super-tab>
<super-tab [root]="page3" title="Third page"></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

Using the Ionic slides works as well but, depending on the complexity, you will run into problems when using things like headers, footers, refreshers and infinite scrolls.